# How can i show one AlertDialog every 24h?

Tags: android, kotlin

I making app with tracking how long you are wearing lenses.

I want to make functional like this: every 24h (for example it should update at midnight) my app should show AlertDialog with a question but it should be only one time at day.

For example i'm user. I woke up at morning, open app and i see dialog "wearing lenses?" and if i close this alert it should show up again only after midnight. And if i don't open my app all day this alert should be destroyed before next will show up i guess...

I hope you get my question

My information will be saved in SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

Well you could save a timestamp in sharedprefs, if currentTimestamp - savedTimestamp > 24hr show dialog and save the new timestamp. or save date and if its a newer date then show and save the new date.

Comment: Thank you. I think date will be safer. I will try to use it

Comment: I wanted to ask. What about lifecycle of this alert? After 24h will it be deleted and new one will be showed or a new one will be layerd to a previous one?

Answer (score 0):

You can always schedule a worker that will repeat every 24 hours. Unfortunately while doing that, you can only schedule delay, not specific time the worker should be triggered.

```
private fun scheduleWorker() {
    val workerTag = "workerTag"
    val periodicWork =
        PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(QrCodeWorker::class.java, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addTag(workerTag)
            .build()
    WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
        .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(workerTag, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, periodicWork)
}
```

In your custom worker you need to override `doWork` function like this:

```
override fun doWork(): Result {
        // send notification
        return Result.success()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it later